# Galaxy s2 data retrieval

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

Galaxy S2 lcd broken, totally black screen. Would like to retrieve data through kies but as phone is swipe protected, kies won't unlock it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How about a MHL HDMI adapter? With a bluetooth mouse? Depends how much the data is worth to you I guess.

Comment: So the defunct phone screen would be mirrored on either a tv or pc and b/tooth mouse to trace the swipe pattern? How to enable b/t tooth on phone though?